# Save checkbox values

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsuserdefaults

As many others here I am new to Xcode and would like to ask a basic question. When checking a box and leaving Xcode, this value is not saved (unchecked box) when I reopen the Xcode project.

I have seen different discussions here: e.g. how to save a checkbox value check/uncheck to NSUserDefaults but it is not working in my code. Do you have a hint where the problem is?

In my .h I have created an instance of a BOOL (called “checked“) and a UIButton is connected both as an IBAction and as an IBOutlet.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
checked = NO;
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"Negative"];
BOOL checked = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"Negative"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

[super viewDidLoad];

NSUserDefaults *defaults70 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
checked = [defaults70 boolForKey: @"boxIsChecked70"];
[self checkTheBox];   
 [self updateLabels];}

- (IBAction)CheckCOUTCheckButton:(id)sender {
NSUserDefaults *defaults70 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if (! checked) {
    [_CheckBoxCOUTButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Checkboxcheckedimage.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    checked = YES;
    [defaults70 setBool:checked forKey:@"boxIsChecked70"];}
else if (checked) {
    [_CheckBoxCOUTButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Checkboxuncheckedimage.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    checked = NO;
    [defaults70 setBool:checked forKey:@"boxIsChecked70"];}
[defaults70 synchronize];}



- (void) checkTheBox {
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if (! checked) {
    [_CheckBoxCOUTButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Checkboxuncheckedimage.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
else if (checked) {
    [_CheckBoxCOUTButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Checkboxcheckedimage.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}

- (IBAction)ClearAllFields:(id)sender {
[_CheckBoxCOUTButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Checkboxuncheckedimage.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
checked = NO;}
```

Comment: It's Xcode, not xCode.  And Xcode is an IDE--not a compiler, not a programming language--and has nothing to do with your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is an problem of scope.  You are defining a second variable called checked and confusing which one you're setting.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
checked = NO;
```

in this line you are setting the property - ie the self.checked value to NO.

> BOOL checked = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"Negative"];
>   [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

in this line however you are declaring a NEW local variable that will only exist within viewDidLoad.

try removing the BOOL before it.   When viewDidLoad returns this local variable will go out of scope and disappear.

> checked = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"Negative"];
>   [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

so later on when you set the checkbox as part of checkTheBox you're reading the property, not your local variable that you set.

let me know if this isn't clear.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is your only problem, but in your viewDidLoad, you are basically setting a value before you're reading it:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"Negative"];
BOOL checked = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"Negative"];
```

You probably want to do this:

```
BOOL checked = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"Negative"];
```